# My INNER JOIN is filtering out too much

Tags: sql, sql-server

My INNER JOIN is filtering out too much or I can't see what the difference is.

I am trying to consolidate 2 tables from 2 different databases on the same server.

My first step is to find all the values that match:

```
SELECT intl.*
FROM   tblData intl
INNER JOIN [db].dbo.tblData us
ON     intl.DataID = us.DataID
AND    intl.AnotherID = us.AnotherID
AND    intl.DataValue = us.DataValue
AND    intl.TextValue = us.TextValue
AND    intl.DefaultValue = us.DefaultValue
AND    intl.RateValue = us.RateValue
AND    intl.YetAnotherID = us.YetAnotherID
```

I've checked all the columns and they are the same type and same varchar values.  So this query should bring back all the matching values.

However... That is not the case.  It is only returning 200+ records, where if I run this query after I insert the 200+ records into a temp table:

```
SELECT intl.DataID
FROM   tblData intl
LEFT JOIN TempDataTable TDT
ON     TDT.DataID = intl.DataID
AND    TDT.AnotherID = intl.AnotherID
AND    TDT.DataValue = intl.DataValue
AND    TDT.TextValue = intl.TextValue
AND    TDT.DefaultValue = intl.DefaultValue
AND    TDT.RateValue = intl.RateValue
AND    TDT.YetAnotherID = intl.YetAnotherID
WHERE  TDT.DataID IS NULL
```

This query returns 1500+ rows.

I've run a similar query with the US data and found the same discrepancy (1500+ rows returned).

I looked at 1 record just to see if I could identify something whacky, and I found that the records from each table (INTL and US) are EXACTLY the same!

```
 DataID: 1
 AnotherID: 1
 DataValue: NULL
 TextValue: NORMAL
 DefaultValue: 0
 RateValue: NULL
 YetAnotherID: 1
```

I imagine my inner join is finding a difference between the 2 tables structurally but I can not see it.

Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: Likely the `NULL` values.  `NULL` is not equal to anything, not even another `NULL`.  So where it's comparing the `NULL` columns, it would fail the equality check, thus inflating your `LEFT JOIN` numbers.

Comment: Really...  I did not know that.  Do you have any suggestions to get this to work or should I not match on the columns that could be NULL at all?

Comment: One way to handle this is converting those nulls to real values: `coalesce(TDT.DataValue, '!@#$%') = coalesce(TDT.DataValue, '!@#$%')`

Comment: That worked!  If you want to put it as a solution I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @webdad3 Thx. Just glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by the `NULL` values that you have in the table failing the equality checks of your `LEFT JOIN`.

`NULL` values aren't equal to anything, not even to another `NULL` of the same datatype.

To remedy this, you can add a check to the `ON` clause for `NULL` values on both sides in addition to the existing `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT intl.DataID
FROM   tblData intl
LEFT JOIN TempDataTable TDT
    ON  (
            (TDT.DataID IS NULL AND intl.DataID IS NULL)            
            OR TDT.DataId = intl.DataId
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.AnotherID IS NULL AND intl.AnotherID IS NULL)      
            OR TDT.AnotherId = intl.AnotherId
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.DataValue IS NULL AND intl.DataValue IS NULL)      
            OR TDT.DataValue = intl.DataValue
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.TextValue IS NULL AND intl.TextValue IS NULL)      
            OR TDT.TextValue = intl.TextValue
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.DefaultValue IS NULL AND intl.DefaultValue IS NULL) 
            OR TDT.DefaultValue = intl.DefaultValue
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.RateValue IS NULL AND intl.RateValue IS NULL) 
            OR TDT.RateValue = intl.RateValue
        )
    AND (
            (TDT.YetAnotherID IS NULL AND intl.YetAnotherID IS NULL) 
            OR TDT.YetAnotherID = intl.YetAnotherID
        )
WHERE  TDT.DataID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this approach to dealing with `NULL` equality comparisons.

[More details about it here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

```
SELECT intl.*
FROM   tblData intl
       INNER JOIN [db].dbo.tblData us
         ON EXISTS (SELECT intl.DataID,
                           intl.AnotherID,
                           intl.DataValue,
                           intl.TextValue,
                           intl.DefaultValue,
                           intl.RateValue,
                           intl.YetAnotherID,
                    INTERSECT
                    SELECT us.DataID,
                           us.AnotherID,
                           us.DataValue,
                           us.TextValue,
                           us.DefaultValue,
                           us.RateValue,
                           us.YetAnotherID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Values null not take in your query. Use isnull(value, 0) for type value number and isnull(value, '') for type value chararctere

  SELECT intl.DataID
  FROM   tblData intl
  inner JOIN TempDataTable TDT
  ON     isnull(TDT.DataID, 0) = isnull(intl.DataID, 0)
  AND    isnull(TDT.AnotherID, 0) = isnull(intl.AnotherID, 0)
  AND    isnull(TDT.DataValue, '') = isnull(intl.DataValue, '')
  AND    isnull(TDT.TextValue, '') = isnull(intl.TextValue, '')
  AND    isnull(TDT.DefaultValue, 0) = isnull(intl.DefaultValue, 0)
  AND    isnull(TDT.RateValue, '') = isnull(intl.RateValue, '')
  AND    isnull(TDT.YetAnotherID, 0) = isnull(intl.YetAnotherID, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You `INNER JOIN` is doing what it should and that is returning **only** rows from tblData (us) and tblData (international) where **all** of your tdt = intl condtions apply. If it is a `NULL` value then `coalesce()` would be what you want to use. Consider this:

```
select 1 where null = null
select 2 where coalesce(null,2) = coalesce(null,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

[EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) can be good for this query.

```
SELECT 
    intl.DataID
FROM   
    tblData intl
WHERE
    NOT EXIST
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 FROM TempDataTable TDT
        WHERE
            TDT.DataID = intl.DataID AND
            TDT.AnotherID = intl.AnotherID AND
            TDT.DataValue = intl.DataValue AND
            TDT.TextValue = intl.TextValue AND
            TDT.DefaultValue = intl.DefaultValue AND
            TDT.RateValue = intl.RateValue AND
            TDT.YetAnotherID = intl.YetAnotherID
     )
```